# CloudWatch - Graph Log Stream consumption

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, metrics, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am trying to graph the IncomingLogEvents or IncomingBytes or PutLogEvents or whatever metric that would help me understand which log streams are the ones sending the most logs to a specific log group in Cloudwatch

Did anyone run into this? I was able to graph the IncomingBytes metric for log groups but not for logstreams within those log groups

I have several containers in my environment and each container sends their logs through a separate log stream within the same log group

Suddenly costs started rising due to errors on the containers and was able to identify which log group is causing it but I cannot find a way to identify which logstream is

Docker does not help either and of course I can check container logs but I want to be able to alert on an increase, hence detect when a logstream is sending more logs than normal as it will alert me on cost increase as on errors

I know I can monitor log errors with other log centralization tools or even with CloudWatch but need to know from Cloudwatch which container is the one sending the highest amount of logs

There used to be a metric that got deprecated and I cannot find any documentation that would help me use whatever metric or solution they replaced it with

The metric was "storedBytes": 0 which from now on, and since deprecation it will always be 0

Thank you for any help that you can provide me with and hope this question help others achieve their goals too
Eu

Cloudwatch dashboard but can make it for log groups only